# Is being a fan haram?

Tags: halal-haram, doubts, music

Assalamu Alaikum.
I am a 16 years old girl.
I like a boy band named BTS. I used to enjoy their music and performance. But now that I am aware that it's haram to listen to music i am trying to stay away from music. But there are some things I am confused about. I like enjoying their variety show and other fun activities. Which mostly doesn't contain music or any haram activities. It's mostly fun games and stuff. Is it okay if I still watch those shows and clips? I am not excessively obsessed. It's just something I like to watch.
I would like to know if it's acceptable or not.
Thank you.

Comment: Walekum assalaam wa rehmatullahi wa barakatuhu sister. Your question is too difficult to answer without knowing exactly what type of content it is.

In general it is not recommend to be a fan of or have liking for people who are mostly into haram or sinful acts. As it will only act as an invitation for you towards sins.

Therefore, one should avoid it. Also, it is not recommended for a Muslim to waste time. Rather, we should spend time in things which will be useful in this world or Hereafter.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will keep that in mind. To answer your question, the show is mostly like some mission to pass games. Like dominos or puzzles and quiz. Or playing tennis matches things like that.

Answer (score 2):

Wa Alaykum Al Salam Wa Rahmut Allah Wa Barakatuh. Masha' Allah! First of all sister, it's wonderful that you're stepping away from music as it's haram. Unfortunately, many people from the younger generations got addicted to it. So, AlHamdulillah that Allah has blessed you by stepping away from it because it fills your heart with void and turns your mind away from things that matter in life while ruining your mental clarity and concentration.

Second, being a fan of celebrities is most often not recommended, as continuously watching them will affect/shape you in one way or another, whether you feel it or not, because if you don't, your subconscious mind will, and hence your behavior will change accordingly. So it is of wisdom that one makes sure he chooses the right, righteous, positively influential person as an example. And what better example do we have other than The Prophet peace be upon him and his companions?

Third, watching these celebrities do activities like games and whatnot is not forbidden for itself (unless it contains haram things like nudity, drinking, gambling, etc.). Still, I'm afraid that watching them back to back and waiting for their new uploads will eventually lead to addiction. Then it'll be more challenging to quit, as your nafs (self) might get attached to them and thus feel empty/hollow when not watching them. That being said, it doesn't hurt to watch such fun stuff from time to time as long as it's not encouraging sinful acts or contains some itself.

Therefore sister, I would recommend being mindful of what you watch, and always remember that Allah is watching you, so make sure to watch what pleases Allah Subhanahu Wa Ta'ala. Also, try watching other useful/valuable Islamic content on youtube that will be beneficial for you here and the hereafter. There's this new series on youtube about the Life of The Prophet ﷺ from authentic sources if you're interested!

And lastly, you asking this question shows that you're sincere, **which is really beautiful**, and I ask Allah The All-Mighty to keep you steadfast on your deen!